# Что нужно знать специалисту по информационной безопасности?

Tags: безопасность, веб-программирование

Какие знания необходимы специалисту по информационной безопасности. О себе: есть знания языков программирования C и Perl, а также опыт в написании эксплойтов и вредоносных программ. Я конечно понимаю, что этого не достаточно, но что еще необходимо такому специалисту? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: [24 смертных греха компьютерной безопасности][1]


  [1]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5238324/

Comment: Окей, еще есть книги наподобие ей.

Answer (score 3):

Контроль соблюдения правил безопасности при разработке ПО, т.е. знать о возможных уязвимостях, уметь их находить и исправлять (В большинстве случаев исправлением занимаются программисты). Отличные знания в области криптографии так же важны. Собственно в каждой компании свои требования по языкам программирования. Ну и сто процентов сейчас нужны специалисты как раз таки по востребованным языкам типа Java / C# / C / PHP.

Вообще по-сути административные вопросы тоже на специалиста по ИБ ложатся, ибо со стороны закона очень большие ограничения в плане криптографии и защиты данных, плюс создание документации по ГОСТам, да и разграничение прав доступа для сотрудников фирмы.

Тема эта очень сложная, и одним программированием тут не отделаться